# Cursor to gain the number of cars each person owns

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am a new with Oracle and DBMS and I have two tables CAR_OWNER and CAR. I am trying to get the number of cars each person owns by using Cursor and loop but should I do I by Join? or there is a specific function to do that?.
Below is my code:

```
declare 
    v_PNR CAR_OWNER.PNR%TYPE;
    i  NUMBER;

    cursor c_custcell is
        select First_name, Last_Name, PNR from CAR_OWNER;
begin
    i:=1;

    if not (c_custcell%isopen) then
        open c_custcell;
    end if;

    loop
        i := i +1;
        exit when i = 11; 

        fetch c_custcell into v_First_name, v_Last_name, v_PNR;
        exit when c_custcell%notfound;

        dbms_output.put_line(''||initcap (v_First_name)||',  '||initcap (v_Last_name)||',   '||v_PNR||',   '||i||','); 

    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't really need PL/SQL to do that, I suppose that you chose that approach for studying purposes.

You didn't share tables' description so I'll (partially) guess. Anyway, I hope you'll get the idea.

Instead of explicitly declaring a cursor and handling *everything* (declare it, open, fetch, take care about exiting the loop, closing the cursor), I'm using the cursor FOR loop because Oracle does most of that *dirty* job for me.

```
begin
  -- Select all owners. I presume that there must be some kind of the "ID"
  -- column which is used to enforce referential integrity constraint between
  -- cars and their owners. I'll use that "ID" column later, while selecting
  -- number of cars per each person
  for cur_r in (select o.first_name, o.last_name, o.owner_id
                from car_owner o
               )
  loop
    -- count number of cars for that OWNER_ID
    select count(*)
      into l_cnt
      from car c
      where c.owner_id = cur_r.owner_id;

    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.first_name||' '||cur_r.last_name ||
         ' owns ' || l_cnt || ' cars');
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to group by the owner and `count`:

```
SELECT   INITCAP(first_name), INITCAP(last_name), COUNT(*)
FROM     car_owners
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you should use a cursor for this, nor do I think you need one. Something like this should do the trick - but please note that I’m making some assumptions about your tables so you’ll need to adjust the query to meet your need:

```
SELECT co.First_name, co.Last_name, COUNT(c.ID) as Number_of_cars 
FROM CAR_OWNER co 
JOIN CAR c ON co.ID = c.OWNER_ID 
GROUP BY co.First_name, co.Last_name
```

That will get you all of the owners who have at least one car; if you want to get ALL owners even if they have 0 cars, then change JOIN to LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Well, I am obligated to use a cursor. Its is required.

Comment: @Yas Is this a school assignment?

Comment: @Yes, it is and I am stuck with it